# How to enable "Min Free Stack" and "Run Time (%)" in STM32CubeIDE?

Tags: task, load, stm32

I am trying to add more information in my debugging. And I found information about "Min Free Stack" and "Run Time (%)" is missing in "FreeRTOS Task List":

[image]

I googled this, and found something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34729422/freertos-vtaskgetruntimestats) for example. but I couldn't find any explanation to do this by using "ioc" GUI.

My board is nucleo-f767zi.

If I have to define these two lines:

```
#define portCONFIGURE_TIMER_FOR_RUN_TIME_STATS()    vConfigureTimerForRunTimeStats()
#define portGET_RUN_TIME_COUNTER_VALUE()            vGetTimerForRunTimeStats()
```

how can I define vConfigureTimerForRunTimeStats() and vGetTimerForRunTimeStats() by combination of using ioc file and source file? Or is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. All the details are in the UM2609 - User manual -
STM32CubeIDE user guide (Rev 5 - November 2021) in my case. "6. RTOS-aware debugging" describes how to enable the stack usage.

I missed `configRECORD_STACK_HIGH_ADDRESS`.

```
#define configRECORD_STACK_HIGH_ADDRESS             1
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about the Run Time tab, but what worked for me for the Min Free Stack was just toggling the three horizontal lines that are just above the window in your picture.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqhR3.png)